# PDO / MySQL / PHP - Issue with my query result being cached

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am almost certain my query is being cached. It is a SELECT statement.

Here is an example situation. There are currently 2 pending orders. I have a script that displays a notification of pending orders on the home page to notify the warehouse if any new orders have been placed. I placed an order to test out if the "2" would update to "3" and it didn't. I think my query is being cached, because when I run the query from phpMyAdmin it shows "3" but when ran through PHP it only shows "2". Any ideas how to fix this or disable caching on specific queries?

Here was my original code

```
<?php
if( protectThis("1, 2") ) :
$pending = $conn->query("SELECT count(*) FROM orders WHERE `status` =0");
$pending2 = $pending->fetch();
$pendingcount = count($pending2);
if ($pendingcount > 0) {
?>
<div class="orange warning">
    <p>
        <strong>Pending Order Notification</strong>
        <br />There are currently <strong><?php echo $pendingcount; ?></strong> pending orders.
        <br /><a style="color:white;margin-top:10px;" class="btn btn-inverse" href="orders_pending.php"><i>Click here to view them.</i></a>
    </p>
    <div class="shadow-out"></div>
</div>
<?php
}
endif;
```

I tried altering the query after reading up on trying to disable the caching for specific queries and tried the following

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE count(*) FROM orders WHERE `status` =0
```

Apparently that didn't work either.

I'm not sure what to do. :\

Any help is much appreciated.

---

"EDIT 1"

```
$pending = $conn->query("SELECT count(*) FROM orders WHERE `status` =0");
// $pending2 = $pending->fetch();
// $pendingcount = count($pending2);
$pendingcount = $pending->rowCount();
if ($pendingcount > 0) {
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are counting the wrong way. Try `var_dump($pending2)`. I guess you'll get this output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(3)
  ["COUNT(*)"]=>
  int(3)
}
```

`$pending2` is an array containing the only row your query returned, with the only column indexed by both column name and 0-indexed column number. Any single-row resultset will look like this, and if you `count` it, it will always output `2`.

So instead of this:

```
$pendingcount = count($pending2);
```

you should use this:

```
$pendingcount = $pending2[0];
```

Comment: Awesome. That worked. Now, is there some way I can set specific queries to not be cached? because I have another page that shows a list of registered users and I added a user, and he never showed up in the list until like 1-2 hours later and countless page refreshes.

Comment: [`SQL_NO_CACHE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-cache-in-select.html) should work as you used it. If you still see outdated data, it could be something else. Maybe some PHP framework, or your browser?

Comment: For some reason the var_dump is a string and not integer

Comment: array(2) { ["count(*)"]=> string(1) "3" [0]=> string(1) "3" }

Comment: even though `status` in my dB is set to int(11). That shouldnt be a problem right?

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem. I don't know who is converting it (maybe MySQL itself, or PDO), but PHP will take care of converting to the appropriate type when necessary.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the count value, you could use [PDO::fetchColumn](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) method.

```
$pendingcount = $conn->query("SELECT count(*) FROM orders WHERE `status` =0")
                     ->fetchColumn();
```